# Loading indicator as component templateURL resolves/loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have been working with AngularJS 1.6 for a few months now and consider myself fairly adept at the framework at this point, however, I have come across a problem that I am having trouble resolving.

I have many custom Components that I use within my app, several of which I load into modals using UIB-Modals from the UI-Bootstrap library. I have noticed that on the first open/load of modals in which I have a component that must load its template from a templateURL, the modal first opens empty, and then the template fills in a quarter of a second later (or more depending on ping and download speed).

I would really like to display some kind of loading icon/spinner while the template downloads in the cases where it is the first time the modal has been opened and Angular has not yet cached the template. (I believe I could accomplish this by using an Angular Directive link function + some JQuery, however I would much much prefer to continue using components as they are easier and the current way that I have been creating new reusable ui elements).

If you know of a way that I could continue using components while acquiring this feature I would be most greatful!

Comment: I believe you could add a loading indicator and remove it after a `$timeout()` of 0 in your component controller. The timeout should afaik be fired only after the template has been loaded.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I will give that a try! Thanks for the suggestion!